# Sorting values in ascending and descending using jquery

Tags: jquery

```
$1 = 10;
$2 = 30;
$3 = 5;

$("#bidtmp").val('');

if ($1 > $2) {
    $("#bidtmp").val('1');
} else if ($2 > $3) {
    $("#bidtmp").val('2');
} else if ($3 > $1) {
    $("#bidtmp").val('3');
} else if ($1 > $3) {
    $("#bidtmp").val('1');
} else if ($2 > $1) {
    $("#bidtmp").val('2');
} else if ($3 > $2) {
    $("#bidtmp").val('3');
}
```

how to sort values in ascending order using jquery? Above is the code what i have tried?

Comment: What actually you need to sort , do you want to sort those variables , declared or do you want to sort the values in the $bidtmp , Could you please elaborate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try:

```
$("#bidtmp").val( Math.max($1, $2, $3) );
```

From your code it seem you're trying to set max value to `#bidtmp` and for that above will work.

But for sorting try ***[sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)*** method like below:

```
[$1, $2, $3].sort(function(a, b) {
  return a-b;
});
```

for descending `return b-a;`.

Answer (score 4):

This is way super complicated ;)

Try this instead:

```
var arr = [$1, $2, $3]
arr.sort() // asc
arr.sort().reverse() // desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var $1 = 10, $2 = 30, $3 = 20;
var sorted_arr = [$1, $2, $3].sort();
```

Do not forget to declare vars.

[Sort](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp) method can get a function as argument for custom sort.

Comment: The default sort for numbers is "wrong" in most cases. `arr = [10, 30,  5]; arr.sort(); arr[0]` results in 20, not 5